# Redirect dynamic url to home page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect dynamic URL to homepage, URL has 4 parameters

> http://example.com/abc.php?slug=Adjective&getId=2&sub_id=1&inner_id=67

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the dynamic URL to homepage , you can use the following rule,

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ℅{THE_REQUEST} /abc.php\?slug=Adjective&getId=2&sub_id=1&inner_id=67\s [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]
```

This will redirect http://abc.php?slug=Adjective&getId=2&sub_id=1&inner_id=67 to http://example.com/ .

Do not remove the question mark **?** from the Rewrite destination as this discards the old querystring.